# Parsing CVS History Output

Tags: regex, cvs

I just need to get a list of the most recent changes from CVS and parse them.

**Example:** The CVS user "Lollerskates" checked in a file with spaces. But spaces are the delimiter! And then "skates" checked in a file with a space in a folder name.

```
% cvs history -c -a -D 2011-03-14
A 2011-03-15 00:17 +0000 jschmoe      1.1   CoolCode.java                  Awesome/Source/Java/src/com/widgets/foo/ambiguous/abstraction   == <remote>
M 2011-03-15 00:17 +0000 sumbody      1.2   MoreCoolCode.java              Awesome/Source/Java/src/com/widgets/foo/ambiguous/abstraction   == <remote>
A 2011-03-15 00:17 +0000 lollerskates 1.123 This File Name Has Spaces.html Awesome/Source/Java/src/com/widgets/foo/ambiguous/abstraction   == <remote>
A 2011-03-15 00:17 +0000 jschmoe      1.1   MyAwesomeProject.java          Awesome/Source/Java/src/com/widgets/foo/ambiguous/abstraction   == <remote>
M 2011-03-15 00:17 +0000 skates       1.5   BlahBlah.java                  Awesome/Source/Java/src/com/widgets/foo/content/block type/cart == <remote>
```

What is a *reliable* way to parse this?

Alternatively, is there a different CVS command with more easily parsable results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex captures all of these:

```
\w \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2} \+\d{4} (\w+)\s+(\d+.\d+)\s+([\w\s]+\.\w+)\s+([\w\s/]+)== \<remote\>
```

The user is in group #1, filename in group #3 and path in group #4.

Comment: Normally there may be filenames without dot and directory paths with dots. So filename and directory tuple could be **file name module name/bla.bla**.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the problems I ran into with this regular expression. I modified it for use with my particular application, adding support for the dots and dashes: `(?P<action>\w) (?P<datetime>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}) (?P<offset>\+\d{4}) (?P<username>\w+)\s+(?P<revision>[\d.]+)\s+(?P<filename>.+)\s+(?P<directory>.+[^\s])[\s]+== \<remote\>`

Answer (score 0):

In this very case probably `cut` is a better way? If the fields are fixed length...

Comment: For a given set, yes, the fields are all the same length. The trick is determining what that length is.

Comment: @ElephantHunter: Could be done by analyzing the position of the first nonspace around the start of the module part. If you know the module name it's not 100% reliable, but easier. Otherwise statistical analysis must give the answer. And then it's easy:)

Comment: @ElephantHunter: Unsolvable in general case with this output… Alas! So everything shall be more or lass dirty.